# Why am I getting the default vuex store values and not the updated ones for my computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an `initial` (starting) page where the user can press a button to login. Also when in that page I want to know if the user's already logged in or not, so I'm using `mapState` to access the `isLoggedIn` state variable of my store.

In code:

```
 // Initial.vue

 <template>
    <v-container
        app
        fluid
    >
        <v-parallax
            src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/vbanner.jpg"
            height="1000"
        >
            <v-layout
                row
                wrap
            >
                <!-- LOGIN-->

                    <v-toolbar
                        flat
                        light
                        dense
                        color="transparent"
                    >
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-toolbar-items>
                            <v-btn
                                medium
                                color="lime lighten-2"
                                @click="login"
                                class="font-weight-bold title text-uppercase"
                            >
                                LOGIN
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-toolbar-items>
                    </v-toolbar>
            <v-layout
                align-center
                column
            >
                <h1 class="display-2 font-weight-thin mb-3 text-uppercase lime--text lighten-2" >My page</h1>
                <h4 class="subheading">{{isLoggedIn}}</h4>
            </v-layout>

            </v-layout>
        </v-parallax>
    </v-container>
</template>
    <script>
        import VContainer from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VContainer";
        import VLayout from "vuetify/lib/components/VGrid/VLayout";
        import VBtn from "vuetify/lib/components/VBtn/VBtn";
        import VToolbar from "vuetify/lib/components/VToolbar/VToolbar";
        import VParallax from "vuetify/lib/components/VParallax/VParallax";

        import { mapState } from 'vuex';

        export default {
            name: "Initial",
            components: {
                VContainer,
                VLayout,
                VBtn,
                VToolbar,
                VParallax
            },
            //Upon returning to this page isLoggedIn is false eventhough isLoggedIn has been updated to store
            computed: mapState({
                    isLoggedIn: state => state.isLoggedIn
                }), 
            methods: {
                login() {
                    this.$auth.login();
            },
            }


        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>

    </style>
```

After the user logs in (via `auth0`) he gets redirected to the registration form. Upon form submit the data are sent to the back-end, I'm invoking a `REGISTER` action to update the store state and then redirect to `/home`. The code that does that is:

```
 //CompleteSignup.vue

    this.$store.dispatch(REGISTER,registerFormData)
              .then(() => this.$router.push('/home'));
```

And my store is this:

```
//index.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {APIService} from '@/common/api.service';

import {REGISTER} from "./actions.type";
import {SET_ERROR, SET_AUTH} from "./mutations.type";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',

  state: {
    errors: null,
    user: {},
    isLoggedIn: false

  },

  getters: {
    currentUser(state) {
      return state.user;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    [REGISTER]({commit}, registerData) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          APIService.create(registerData)
            .then(({data}) => {
              commit(SET_AUTH, data);
              resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(({response}) => {
                commit(SET_ERROR, response.data.errors);
                reject(response);
            });
      });
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    [SET_ERROR](state, error) {
      state.error = error;
    },
    [SET_AUTH](state, user) {
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.user = user.user_id;
      state.errors = {};
    }

  }

})
```

When I'm in `/home` I can see from the Vue devtools that my store variables are correctly updated:

[image: vuex store]

*The problem appears when I'm navigating back to the `/initial` page.* I would expect that when the user would go back to that view, the `computed` value `isLoggedIn` would return `true`; but instead I'm getting the default store value (`false`).

**Why is `mapState` not returning `true` for the `isLoggedIn` store variable**?

Also -though I'm not sure it's related- I noticed that in this scenario, `vue devtools` is showing again the first `Base state` of the attached screenshot as the active one (with the same timestamp too).  It's as if the going back action re-triggered the original state instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I've tried to put together a working replica of the problem, but I can't. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-vuerouter-basic-layout-v18h0 - This is working as it is supposed to. Are you able to put together a MVCE in codesandbox? https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the fact that I'm using `auth0` to login. Upon further research though, I believe the reason has to do with full page reloads. I read that when redirecting w/o using `next` a full HTTP reload is triggered resulting in loss of state. I substituted an `auth` call that I had in my router.js with a `next` but I still get the same issue. Could it be `next` that somehow triggers this?

Comment: Is it possible to put a working (with the error) version in a git repo? I'm happy to help you solve it, but without all the code there is little I can do but speculate.

Comment: Thank you @Trent. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to provide a direct link to this but was able to put together this sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-vuerouter-basic-layout-r8lwc?fontsize=14 This is my first time using sandbox so I don't know how to properly make the whole thing work wrt imports etc but you can definitely see my code and get an idea of what's going on.